# Literature about cryptography and programming on c++

Tags: reference-request, cryptocurrency

I'm interested in learning about cryptography and making something practical out of it - make own cryptocurrency sometime im future.

I think I have good knowlegde of c++, I learned from learncpp.com and from Bjarne's books. So first what I need is book about basics of cryptography. After that I would do some practical things so I need something to cover cryptocurrencies in c++.

Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can no-one contribute anything at all? Isn't there a be nice doctrine?

Comment: "make own cryptocurrency sometime im future"; do you mean mining or making your own brand of currency?  Either way, there are fairly formidable challenges that won't be addressed by learning cryptography - for mining, it's hard to match the efficiencies of existing large scale miners; for creating you're own it'd be hard to get other people to trust your brand new currency...

Comment: Making my own brand of cryptocurreny. Do you have any advice for literature? Anything would be a good for start.

Comment: @PaulUszak: Do you mean, opinion based questions are allowed on Crypto SE?

Comment: @mentallurg  It's inevitable given what some old geezer said: _"Remember that all is but opinion and conceit"_.